# Help identifying a martial arts movie with supernatural elements

Tags: story-identification, movie, martial-arts

I am trying to recall a martial arts movie, likely chinese/Hong Kong but not 100% sure. I think I ran into it because of a small interest in *Master of the Flying Guillotine* and wanted more over-the-top 70s ninja or wuxia films that throw a lot of unbelievable stuff at you.

I figure it must be from the 70s. The one thing I recall is an early fight among some trees, perhaps adjacent to a field, where the hero(es) are attacked by three(?) agile assassins, I think wearing large brimmed hats. They can leap from tree to tree and at one point, one horrifyingly spits a large volume of acid or something from their mouth with great force. The other ones maybe also have distinctive supernatural powers.

I figure this sequence is distinctive enough to get an ID, if not I can also investigate any martial arts movies with screwball superpowers in it (like the yoga master from *flying guillotine*).

Comment: As a note, I was sad to discover that movies.stackexchange stopped accepting identify questions. I hope the fact that this specific kung fu movie has fantastical elements makes it germane enough to be allowed here.

Comment: The jumping around and spitting of acid while wearing brimmed hats sounds like something from the Jiangshi movies (supernatural zombie/vampire horror/comedy movies) popular in HK in the 70s and 80s. There must be hundreds of them, though.

Comment: The wide brimmed remind me of Big Trouble in Little China but not much else matches.

Comment: Definitely not a western movie, although the idea that it may have a horror bent is good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I've discovered the culprit: [Ninja Wars](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089691/). It is not Hong Kong and not from the 70s, so I was going the wrong way there. Luckily, the full thing is on YouTube so I was able to confirm that about 15 minutes in, an assassin wearing a big lampshade hat spits yellow acidic bile at a guy in a tree. It checks all my boxes, and though I don't have a rush of recollection (I never watched it all the way through originally), I'm 95% sure this is it.

Answer (score 5):

Is it possibly [Swordsman II, starring Jet Li](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhowGyVfdnY)? It has:

- large brimmed hats
- flying around in trees battles
- a battle adjacent to a field

There may also be some acidic spittle in amongst all of the other crazy techniques (ESSENCE ABSORBING STANCE!)